# Is it possible to induce RF Emissions from a RF enabled Device

Tags: rf, radiation, emissions

Would it be possible to take a device anything such as a wireless router or a wireless video and induce unintentional RF emissions while no power is supplied to the device ? Can you send it some range of RF waves and attempt to measure the RF emissions due to incidental waves (re-radiation) ?

Comment: For example, RFID devices.

Comment: @Chu: Please define power supply in this context. RFID devices harvest power from incident EM fields. So there's power supplied by design.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't perform any useful RF emissions analysis of an active device when it is not powered. A significant part of emissions problems relates to non-linearity (which will depend on the bias point of the junctions). You will also not manage to induce the same level of RF signal.

What you can do is (assuming you have a suitable RF test and development licence, screened room, etc) connect a signal generator to part of a circuit and analyse the harmonic and radiation characteristics of that part. This can tell you about where in a circuit you need to focus your efforts to resolve problems, maybe if you can't determine which direction an interferer is propagating.

Assuming you have a CPU and an RF section in your design, there are probably three different energised states, `CPU only`, `CPU plus receive`, `CPU plus Tx`. The worst state from an emission point of view is when the transmit circuit is active, and a CPU circuit is physically close. From a testing point of view, test with the CPU running and not powered (to find the worst case).

If you have a radio which meets emissions on its own, but it fails with harmonics once you connect to the CPU, no amount of work on the radio will fix the problem - you need to decouple the CPU input pins.

Comment: @Hello everyone. But is it possible to distinguish between unintentional RF radiation by a device's CPU's clock and RF emissions being emitted (unintentional) by a RF embedded device ? The assumption is that the RF embedded device is powered on but not transmitting (ie communicating). Or is it the norm for a powered on RF device to be transmitting perhaps just a broadcast of some sort ?

Comment: Please edit the question to include this, and again clarify what part of the project you are in - initial design, or assessment of an emissions fail.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to take a device anything such as a wireless
>   router or a wireless video and induce unintentional RF emissions while
>   no power is supplied to the device ?

No, if it has no power then it can't emit.

> Can you send it some range of RF waves and attempt to measure the RF
>   emissions due to incidental waves (re-radiation) ?

Emissions come from the originating source (what you "send it") and what you appear to be describing are reflections and yes, you can attempt (and actually) measure these reflections.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly any RF device will emit RF signals if it is exposed to an suitable EM field.

Nearly every RF circuit contains a resonator or at least somehow resonant parts. If you expose this circuit and particularly its antenna to a field that can excite the resonant parts then these parts will store energy harvested from the EM field. If the EM field vanishes, the resonant parts will continue their oscillation while radiating the stored energy. 
In most cases this won't take long as a long post-pulse oscillation is not a desired behaviour but it will happen and with considerable delicate equipment it can be measured.

If the resonator of a RF circuit contains nonlinear parts (e.g. Diodes and Transistors) the circuit can emit frequencies different from the ones contained in the incident EM field.